# Passing data from New activity to old activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to receive data from new Activity to old Activity.

In other words, newer Activity must send intend data to old activity when it finishes.

I've use `setResult(resultcode, NewActivity.this.getIntend);` on newer activity and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data != null) {
        // doing something
    }     
}
```

on old activity. Receives intend data from newer activity.

But this code doesn't work. Always getting data is null.

How to send intent data from finishing Activity to parent activity ?

Also when create new Activity, I am using following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setClass(OldActivty.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I don't understand why always getting null intent data from newer one.

how to fix it ?

Please advice.

Thanks,

Comment: First, your `setResult()` call should not be passing back the Intent you got -- you need to create a new Intent with the data you want to return. Second, you may be calling it too late. If you're waiting for `onDestroy()`, for example, that will be too late. Use `onPause()` or something instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As CommonsWare wrote in his comment you are passing the same Intent back to your Activity that you used to start the Activity.

Try something like the following code:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent();
newIntent.putExtra(key, yourData)
newIntent.putExtra(key2, moreData)

setResult(resultcode, newIntent);
```

In your case the Intent is only needed to store the data that is passed back. Therefor you can use the standard constructor.

Comment: Q: Where this requirement to use new Intent comes from? Why I can't use setResult(resultCode, getIntent())?

Comment: you can use getIntent but you then have to set the data into the intent you got from getIntent()