# Set property in parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When i create a new activity from a class A. Is it then possible to set a property in the parent object (i.e. A) from the new activity?

Comment: What kind of property you want to set in your child activity? You can pass information between activities.

Comment: I don't want to set any information in the child activity but in the parent activity. The child creates an object (a mediaPlayer) and when I go back to the parent object i want to pass a reference to the mediaPlayer back so it doesn't get lost, and I still can control it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is.  If you pass a reference to "class A" to the new Activity, you can call "setter" methods on that original class.  Or you could use the `getParent()` method within the [Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  Or you can use a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) if you want it to a be a permanent property.

Or you can use [setResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694947/passing-data-from-new-activity-to-old-activity).

Comment: but in order to call a setter I need the parent object. How do I get that?